# Totally non hereditary $C^{*}$-subalgebras

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

Assume that $B$ is  a  $C^{*}$ subalgebra of $A$. We say $B$ is  totally non hereditary subalgebra of $A$ if not only $B$ is not  a hereditary subalgebra but also it is not isomorphic to any hereditary subalgebra of $A$.

Example: For every $C^{*}$  algebra $A$, $c(A)$ is  a totally non hereditary subalgebra of $\ell^{\infty}(A)$. Here $c(A)$ and $\ell^{\infty}(A)$ are the algebra of all  convergent and bounded sequence with $A$-elements, respectively.

There are some $C^{*}$ algebras which does not have such subalgebras. Example $\mathbb{C}^{n}$

> To what extent all  $C^{*}$ algebras without totally nonhereditary subalgebras are classified? What are some more examples(other than $\mathbb{C}^{n}$)?
>    **In the topological language, somehow, we are interested in some non trvial example of compact Hausdorff  space $X$ such that each quotient of $X$ is homeomorphic to an  open subset of $X$**.
>
> What is a totally nonhereditary subalgebra of $B(H)$ where $H$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space?  What is  an example  of  a  simple $C^{*}$ algebra which contains  a  totally non hereditary sub $C^{*}$ algebra? Is there any  reference about this concept?

Comment: Let $X$ be a countable successor ordinal. Then each quotient of $X$ is homeomorphic to a clopen subset of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to consider a C*-algebra $A$ with the following property: Every sub-C*-algebra of $A$ is isomorphic to a hereditary sub-C*-algebra of $A$.

We can distinguish two cases:

1. If $A$ is finite-dimensional, then $A$ has to be commutative. Indeed, assume $A\cong M_{k_1}\oplus\ldots\oplus M_{k_l}\oplus\mathbb{C}^n$ for $k_j\geq 2$ (and $j\geq 1$). Then $A$ has a commutative sub-C*-algebra of the form $\mathbb{C}^{k_1}\oplus\ldots\oplus \mathbb{C}^{k_l}\oplus\mathbb{C}^n$, but a commutative hereditary sub-C*-algebra of $A$ has at most $l+n$ points in its spectrum.
2. If $A$ is infinite-dimensional, then it contains commutative sub-C*-algebras $C(X)$ where $X$ is any Peano continuum. Such a C*-algebra has to have `huge' primitive ideal space.

I don't think this property has been considered in the literature before.

Another remark: Every simple C*-algebra (not equal to $0$ or $\mathbb{C}$) contains a non-simple sub-C*-algebra. Every hereditary sub-C*-algebra of a simple C*-algebra is simple again. Therefore, every (nontrivial) simple C*-algebra contains a sub-C*-algebra with the condition you consider.

Similarly, $B(H)$ contains many sub-C*-algebras that are not isomorphic to a hereditary sub-C*-algebras of $B(H)$. This is because the primitive ideal space of $B(H)$ has only two points. Thus, any sub-C*-algebra $A$ of $B(H)$ such that the primitive ideal space of $A$ has at least three points will do.

Comment: I learn from your answer that "simplicity" is a heritage of  a $C^{*}$ algebra for its hereditary subalgebras. what type of other properties could be a heritage? Could you please give a reference which contains about these type of heritages?

Comment: Yes, given a C*-algebra A and a hereditary sub-C*-algebra B of A, the primitive ideal space of B, Prim(B) is (homeomorphic to) an open subset of Prim(A). Let's assume that all C*-algebras are nonzero. Then A is simple if and only if Prim(A) is the one-point space. An open subset of the one-point space contains (at most) one point, therefore B is simple.

Comment: Many properties pass to hereditary sub-C*-algebras: simplicity, real rank zero, stable rank one, being an AF-algebra, purely infinite ... A useful result in this context is Brown's stabilization theorem, in Brown (1977) # Stable isomorphism of hereditary subalgebras of C-algebras [Pac. J. Math. 71]. It says that in a (say separable) C*-algebra, every hereditary sub-C*-algebra is stably isomorphic to the ideal it generates. Thus, every property of C*-algebras that passes to ideals and is preserved under stable isomorphism will pass to hereditary sub-C*-algebras of separable C*-algebras.

Comment: Among these properties, is there a property to shows "$c(A)$ is totally non hereditary subalgebra of $\ell^{\infty}(A)$  for arbitrary A?

Comment: To be honest, I would like to realize whetherre the generalization of corollary 4 at page 7 of this note is a trivial obervation  http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3129:

Comment: Which generalization of Corollary 4 in the mentioned preprint do you mean?

Comment: The generalization is to replace $\mathbb{C}$ with arbitrary  $C^{*}$  algebra  $A$. The corollary 4 is about $c=c(\mathbb{C})$ while the generalization is:"$c(A)$ is  totally nonheretiary subalgebra of $\ell^{\infty}(A)$. So my question which I asked you in previous comment: Among properties which you mentioned, is there a property which implies that c(A) is totally non hereditary subalgebra of  $\ell^{\infty}(A)$.?

Comment: For $A=\mathbb{C}$ I heared  an alternative (and very elegance)proof  from an specialist: His proof was topologic: The one point  compactification of natural numbers is not  homeomorphic  to any open subset of Ston chech  compactification"

Comment: What I read in Corollary 4 is: Assume that $A$ is a projectionless C*-algebra. Let $a$ and $b$ be two orthogonal positive elements. Then $\| \|a\|b- \|a\|b \| = \|a\|\cdot\|b\|$.

Comment: I am sorry for my delay. I am also sorry for my bad writing of the paper: In the same   page(page 7) there is another corollary 4.(at bottom of the page). I was incorrect in the numbering of the corollaries. Now my question: among the property which you mentioned, is there a property which satisfy by $\ell^{\infty}(A)$  but not satisfy by c(A)?